# Translating ddply to dplyr and tidyr code (mutate, unite, spread)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the below data-set:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(6,7,96,216,216,384),
               date = c("2003-03-27", "2003-03-31", "2001-08-01", "2009-05-26", "2009-05-26", "2001-04-05"),
               description = rep("code"),
               variable = rep("schedule"),
               value = c(388,45,95,390,12,10))
```

And I am attempting to translate some old code that used plyr and reshape2 and instead use dplyr and tidyr (the old code takes forever to run).

Here is the old code:

```
data$num <- as.numeric(0)
data1 <- ddply(data, .(id, date), transform, num = cumsum(num+1))
data2 <- within(data1, id2 <- interaction(variable, num))
data3 <- dcast(data2, id + date + description ~ id2)
data3
```

And the output looks like:

```
   id       date description schedule.1 schedule.2
1   6 2003-03-27        code        388         NA
2   7 2003-03-31        code         45         NA
3  96 2001-08-01        code         95         NA
4 216 2009-05-26        code        390         12
5 384 2001-04-05        code         10         NA
```

I did not make it far in my attempt, I used group_by and then attempted to mutate a new variable with num = cumsum(num+1) however it just numbered each row 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

My second guess was to use unite for the `id2` variable, but that also did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your output doesn't make much sense given your input data frame. Are you sure that's exactly what you get, not simply an example of the general structure?

Comment: @joran it should be correct now... i made an edit about 2 minutes after the original post to fix an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr/tidyr`, we group by 'id', 'date', create the 'num' column as `row_number()` with `mutate`, `unite` the two columns ('variable' and 'num) to a single column and use `spread` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(id, date) %>% 
   mutate(num=row_number()) %>% 
   unite(variable1, variable, num, sep=".") %>%
   spread(variable1, value)
#    id       date description schedule.1 schedule.2
#1   6 2003-03-27        code        388         NA
#2   7 2003-03-31        code         45         NA
#3  96 2001-08-01        code         95         NA
#4 216 2009-05-26        code        390         12
#5 384 2001-04-05        code         10         NA
```

Or we can use `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e. v1.9.5.  A convenient function to get the sequence column by grouping columns is `getanID` from `splitstackshape`.  The output will be a 'data.table'.  Then use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(getanID(data, c('id', 'date')), id+date+description~ 
            paste('schedule', .id, sep="."), value.var='value')
```

NOTE: Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: thanks @akrun... i need to run through some tidyr tutorials... not entirely sure how spread (and functions like 'gather') works yet, but seems much easier than reshape2.

Comment: @bpace `gather` is similar to `melt` and `spread` as that of `dcast` without the `fun.aggregate`

Comment: @bpace No problem.  Glad to help you.

Comment: @akrun Thanks very nice! did not know about `unite` in `tidyr` +1